# 他人の編集画面に遷移できないようにしたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

他人の投稿画面に遷移できない設定にしたいです。
Rspecで引っかかってしまい解決できなくなっています。
調べてみましたが解決方法が見つからなかったためアドバイス頂けると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
テスト結果

1) 投稿のテスト 編集のテスト 他人の投稿の編集画面への遷移 遷移できない
     Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq('/books')

       expected: "/books"
            got: "/books/2/edit"

       (compared using ==)
```

```
booksコントローラ

class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    @book.user_id = current_user.id
    @books = Book.all
    if
      @book.save
      flash[:notice] = "successfully"
      redirect_to book_url(@book)
    else
      render :index
    end
  end

  def index
    @book = Book.new
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    if
      @book.update(book_params)
      flash[:notice] = "You have updated book successfully."
      redirect_to book_path(@book.id)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.destroy
    redirect_to books_url
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def correct_user
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    if currect_user != @book.user
       redirect_to user_path(currect_user)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

> 他人の投稿画面に遷移できない設定にしたいです。

- ログイン後のみ参照可能なページ
- deviseなどを使用しており、`current_user`でログイン中のユーザー情報が参照できる
- `user has_many books`

上記を前提としています。

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_book

  def show
    redirect_to books_url if @book.blank?
  end

  def set_book
    @book = current_user.books.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
end
```

一般的なWebサービスの場合は、他人のページにアクセスすると`404`にする場合が多いかと思います。
その場合は以下のようにするのが良いかもしれません。

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_book

  def show
  end

  def set_book
    @book = current_user.books.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

もし以下が不明であれば調べてみてください。

- find, find_byの違い
- findでエラーになった場合の挙動